# How to write better jquery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#anch1").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#mydiv1").offset().top
    }, 1000);
   });

   $("#anch2").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#mydiv2").offset().top
    }, 1000);
   });

   $("#anch3").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#mydiv3").offset().top
    }, 1000);
   });
```

Here is a simple jquery code to scroll to a particular div in the page but it looks really long so Is there a short hand way to write this jquery code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really use numbers at the end of you ids... Which can be a good idea, then use them!

I suggest you use a character to segregate the number from the rest...
Below, I used the `_` and the [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method to get the number.
That way, you can have number of more than one digit.

```js
$("#anch_1,#anch_2,#anch_3").click(function() {
  var EndNumber = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
  console.log(EndNumber);
  
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#mydiv_"+EndNumber).offset().top
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
div{
  height:800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="anch_1">One</a> <a id="anch_2">Two</a> <a id="anch_3">Three</a><br>
<br>

<div id="mydiv_1">Div #1</div>
<div id="mydiv_2">Div #2</div>
<div id="mydiv_3">Div #3</div>
```

As the selector... If the begining is always the same, like `anch_`, you can use the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and the "begin with" operator: `^=`.

That would be `$("[id^='anch_']")`, instead of `$("#anch_1,#anch_2,#anch_3")`.

Answer (score 2):

you can write it in a loop.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  $("#anch" + i).click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#mydiv" + i).offset().top
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   function scroll(elementId) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(elementId).offset().top
    }, 1000);
   }

   $("#anch1").click(scroll.bind(null, "#mydiv1"));
   $("#anch2").click(scroll.bind(null, "#mydiv2"));
   $("#anch3").click(scroll.bind(null, "#mydiv3"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are performing the same kind of functionality on all these elements , it'd be better to change your selectors from the individual ids (e.g. `#anch2` and `#mydiv1`) of the html elements to their respective classes. In that way you will call your `click` and `animate` functions on all of your elements at once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('[id^=#anch]').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").split("");
    id = id[id.length - 1];
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#mydiv" + id).offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe since it does the same thing on all 3?

```
function myFunc(eleID) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(eleID).offset().top
    }, 1000);
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    $("#anch"+i).click(function() {
        myFunc($("#anch"+i));
    });
}
```

Noticed after posting that there was already suggestions with loops and functions